# How to create a external builder for a class with private setters?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is there some way of build a class from a external builder class without letting their setters public? I don't want to allow a invalid instance of a class to exist without the necessary validations.

The only way I found so far is creating a constructor with the required parameters and validations.

I made a example with few properties to be filled, but imagine a case with various.

```
    public class Computer
    {
        public string Motherboard { get; private set; }
        public string RamMemory { get; private set; }
        public string Cpu { get; private set; }

        public Computer(string motherboard, string ramMemory, string cpu)
        {
            ValidateMotherboard(motherboard);
            ValidateRamMemory(ramMemory);
            ValidateCpu(cpu);

            Motherboard = motherboard;
            RamMemory = ramMemory;
            Cpu = cpu;
        }

        private void ValidateMotherboard(string motherboard)
        {
            if (motherboard == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(motherboard));
        }

        private void ValidateRamMemory(string ramMemory)
        {
            if (ramMemory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ramMemory));
        }

        private void ValidateCpu(string cpu)
        {
            if (cpu == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cpu));
            else if (!cpu.ToLower().Contains("ryzen"))
                throw new ArgumentException("Only AMD Ryzen CPU's is good enough.");
        }
    }

    public class ComputerBuilder
    {
        private string _motherboard;
        private string _ramMemory;
        private string _cpu;

        public ComputerBuilder SetMotherboard(string motherboard)
        {
            _motherboard = motherboard;
            return this;
        }

        public ComputerBuilder SetRamMemory(string ramMemory)
        {
            _ramMemory = ramMemory;
            return this;
        }

        public ComputerBuilder SetCpu(string cpu)
        {
            _cpu = cpu;
            return this;
        }

        public Computer Build() => new Computer(_motherboard, _ramMemory, _cpu);
    }
```

I just want to have builders that easies the construction of classes with too much parameters. Any ideias of how do this putting the validations on the builder without allow a invalid instance to exist?

Comment: "a constructor with the required parameters and validations" is how this is done in C#.

Comment: and you can nest classes and have `protected internal` set accessors, so only the parent class could set them, while the subclass itself is public and could be reached as containerclass.subclass. but this is convoluted and there may rarely be a real-world use case that justifies it. autogenerated strongly typed dataset classes used to have that for their datarow classes.

Comment: You could define a `ComputerParameters` structure that contains the required fields, and pass that to a `Create` method. Similar to how [XmlReader.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader.create?view=netframework-4.8) works.

Comment: EdPlunkett this is the way that I'm current using. A DDD approach where a constructor or factory method validate, or call external validators, to check the parameters.
CeeMcSharpface-it initially sounds kind of awkward, but can solve in some situations.
JimMischel I like it. I thought about something similar, passing the builder in the constructor. Something like `public Computer(ComputerBuilder builder);`.